# Evaluate the given complicated double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

> $$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}  e^{\frac{-1}{1-(x^2+y^2)}}\log\Big(\log\big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1-x)^2+(1-y)^2}}\big)\Big)\,dy\,dx.$$

I got this super hard integral while doing an exercise on distributions. The only thing I could think of is to transform it  into polar coordinates. It changes into

> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}  e^{\frac{-1}{1-r^2}}\log\Big(\log\big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{r^2-2r\cos(\theta)-2r\sin(\theta)+2}}\big)\Big)\,r\,dr\,d\theta.$$

But even WolframAlpha couldn't compute this. Does anyone know how to evaluate this?

Edit:- There is no closed form of this integral. If anyone has any suggestions regarding approximations, please comment below.

Comment: Note that $\cos\theta+\sin\theta=\sqrt2\sin(\theta+\pi/4)$.

Comment: Just an idea: you might try to use Green's theorem to convert it to a path integral, then maybe express it as a complex integration. The result will almost certainly contain both $z$ and $\bar z$, but if you can separate them somehow, the residue theorem will be useful. Or you may just have to throw up your hands and accept an approximate value. It looks pretty stable numerically.